# How to properly set object properties in TypeScript with setters and getters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setter, getter-setter

How do you set each property of an object with a setter in TypeScript?

```
export class AuthService {
    private _user:User; // User is my model

    constructor(...){}

    public get user()
    {
        return this._user;
    }

    public set user(value){
        this._user = value;
    }
...
```

Then setting anywhere gives errors when:

```
this.authService.user.id = data.userId;
this.authService.user.isLoggedIn = 'true';
```

MORE:

The user model:

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public email: string,
        public pass: string, 
        public id?: string,
        public fname?: string,
        public lname?: string,
        public isLoggedIn?: string){}
}
```

The error: `Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: so ... what's the error? also, what's the User model?

Comment: @alebianco Updated: I don't just want to solve my specific code problem but rather learn the proper way to set object props with a setter.

Comment: It is not obvious from the code above that `this._user` is properly defined, by reading the error you can be sure that it isn't. Omitting the most important part, `constructor(...){}`, doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the whole `user` object to the setter, but you would need access to all other attributes of the user

```
this.authService.user = {
    id: data.userId,
    isLoggedIn: true
};
```

Alternatively, have individual setters for each property

```
public set id(value){
    this._user.id = value;
}

public set isLoggedIn(value){
    this._user.isLoggedIn = value;
}
```

Which you would call as thus

```
this.authService.id = data.userId;
this.authService.isLoggedIn = 'true';
```

Comment: Awesome, so the other props in the object, such as `fname` must be set to a value or null?

Comment: @BenRacicot not necessarily, but you need to ensure you correctly instantiate the user model first, then it all depends how you want your application to perform

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems clear, you're trying to set attributes on an object that doesn't exist.

if `this.authService.user === null` you cannot set it's properties.

You have first to create a `new User(...)` somewhere and assign it to `this.authService.user` then you can go and change it's properties as needed.